# Upload an image as background for a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am drawing a grid and uploading an image as background on canvas.

When I clear the canvas, both the image and the grid are getting cleared.

I don't want the grid and the uploaded image background of canvas to get cleared.

Can you please help is resolving this?

Comment: paste your code here for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas doesn't differentiate the content - its all a bunch of pixels. When you clear the canvas you have to redraw everything you want to be there. If you have an image an a grid just put those in a method which you call every time you need to update the canvas.

If your image covers the whole canvas you don't need to use the `clearRect()` method. Just redraw your image and grid. You can wrap it up in a method, for example:

```
function clear() {
    //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height); /// if image doesn't cover canvas
    ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);         /// draw your image here
    ... render grid here...
}
```

Then call `clear()` instead of `ctx.clearRect()`.

You can alternatively set the background image on the canvas *element* as any other element using CSS but be aware of that it won't be a part of the canvas bitmap itself you produce using `toDataURL()`. However, if the background is only temporary and not meant as part of any result this can be a good option:

```
canvas.style.background = 'url(urlToImage.png)';
```

You can also have the grid as an image and set both as backgrounds on top of each other.

```
canvas.style.backgroundImage = 'url(urlToImage.png), url(urlToGrid.png)';
```